# Tensorflow: What happens if loss becomes nan?

Tags: tensorflow

During my training the loss becomes `nan` from time to time. However this doesn't seem to affect my neural network training. Does anyone know if tensorflow has some internal handling of `nan` values?

The loss values before and after the `nan` are stable so I guess the learning rate is fine. I rather think that some of the images seem not to contain any sensible information, but I'm not 100% sure yet.

Did anyone have similar experience?
I'm using tensorflow 0.12.1

Comment: Can you try running [add_check_numerics_ops](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/add_check_numerics_ops) (make sure the returned op actually runs in the session, via a direct session.run() or a control dependency)? That will at least tell you where the NaNs are coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually NaNs are "infecting", so once you see one pop up suddenly everything that is updated/computed using the NaN value becomes NaN as well.

What happens in your case is, I guess, that the NaN value only happens in the very last step of computing the loss and is not affecting the gradients (which don't need the value of the loss). If you use something like cross entropy, do you get exact 0s/1s in your predictions? For numerical stability, it can be good to use TF's loss functions that have the softmax/sigmoid integrated and not do the softmax/sigmoid yourself.